# Change Font WebView AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, html, webview

I've got a problem with HTML: I want to use a custom Font in a webview but it doesnt't change the Font by using this code:

```
 public void loadHTLMContentText(String text, WebView view) {

    String body;
    String head = "<head><style type=\"text/css\">\n" +
            "@font-face {\n" +
            "    font-family: Bamini;\n" +
            "    src: url(\"Bamini.ttf\")\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "body {\n" +
            "    font-family: Bamini;\n" +
            "    font-size: medium;\n" +
            "    text-align: justify;\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "</style></head>";
    if (text != null) {
        body = text;
    } else return;
    String htmlData = "<html>" + head + "<body style=\"font-family: bamini\">" + body + "</body></html>";


    view.loadData(htmlData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
    view.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

}
```

The ttf-file is in the same folder as the .java.

```
layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        HTMLPre preparer = new HTMLPre();


        View one = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_type_a, container, false);


        WebView header_1_a = (WebView) one.findViewById(R.id.header_slide_type_a_1);
        preparer.loadHTLMContentHeader(getString(R.string.Historie1_header),header_1_a);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The ttf-file is in the same folder as the .java

That is pointless for two reasons:

- Android doesn't typically use random files alongside the Java classes
- `WebView` doesn't know about any of that, anyway

Create an `src/main/assets/` directory (assuming that you are working in a typical Android Studio project). Put your font files there. Use `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, using `file:///android_asset/` as the URL. Then, hope for the best.

Comment: So the difference between loadData and loadDataWithBaseURL is that I transfer the path of the assets? So I think this will solve my problem because the font wasn't found. I'll try it later.

Comment: @LJulz: The difference between `loadData()` and `loadDataWithBaseURL()` is that you can use relative paths, like `"Bamini.ttf"`, in your HTML. You then need to move the font someplace for which you can specify a URL. I assume that your goal is to package the fonts with your app, and `assets/`, coupled with `file:///android_asset/`, is the right combination for `WebView`.

Comment: Wow you helped me a lot, Thank you !